# Setting SqlDateTime.Null in a constructor

Tags: .net, sql, vb.net, datetime

How do I set a null value for an optional DateTime parameter in a constructor?

I'm using the following constructor below and I want the optional parameter admissionDate to be a null DateTime.  Setting it to Nothing actually gives it a value (something like #12:00:00 #).

```
Public Sub New(ByVal obj1 as Object, Optional ByVal admissionDate As DateTime = System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.Null)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest using James Curran's solution but use Overloading instead of an optional parameter, as a workaround for the error you mentioned ("Optional parameters cannot have structure types") :

```
Public Sub New(ByVal obj1 As Object, ByVal admissionDate As Nullable(Of DateTime))
  //Your code here
End Sub

Public Sub New(Byval obj1 As Object)
  Me.New(obj1, Nothing)
End Sub
```

You can also use DateTime? instead of Nullable(Of DateTime) in the latest version of VB (not sure about the older versions).

Comment: I basically used this solution with overloading (two constructors).  But I used SqlDateTime.Null instead of Nothing.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need a Nullable DateTime.  In C#, that's `Nullable<DateTime>` or `DateTime?`.  I'm not sure of the VB.NET syntax, but I think it's something like `Nullable(Of DateTime)`

```
 Public Sub New(ByVal obj1 as Object, _
        Optional ByVal admissionDate As Nullable(Of DateTime) = Null)
```

Comment: I'm getting the error: 

Optional parameters cannot have structure types

Answer (score 2):

I normally use DateTime.MinValue to represent a null date/time.

Answer (score 2):

System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime is not the same as builtin datetime.

You can use that type or use a nullable datetime.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `DBNull.Valu`e?